# Developing an app in visual studio code using python

Tags: python, android, ios, visual-studio

I’m kinda new to programming and the only programming language I'm kinda familiar with at the moment is python. I heard visual studio code can develop an app for both ios and android devices. However, can the visual studio code accept any programming language? Like, let's say I created a code using python, can the visual studio code develop it right away?

Comment: Visual studio code is a software app that allows you to edit text. It is not tide to any language. Developing for IOS or Android depends on language, but not on the editor that you're using. From your question it seems like you don't understand primary concepts of app development or programming, so you better study this first.

Comment: I second what Tino said. Since you are new, it'd be best to familiarize yourself with the various tutorials and literature on how to actually develop apps for iOS and android devices. From my experience it seems _swift_ is used to develop for iOS while for android, _kotlin_ is used. It'd be best to try find examples on github, youtube, medium etc. Start taking baby steps or you'd feel a bit overwhelmed. Simply by start coding is what will actually speed up your understanding of programming. A simple project such as tictactoe in swift would help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

VS Code has an official Python module that works very well so no problems on that front. However, developing for either iOS or Android comes with some additional concerns: in both cases, Python is not "native" on those platforms, so you have to include Python with your app, and there are no "official" Pythons for either platform.  You can do it (read up, for example, on a platform/framework called Kivy), but quite frankly if those two specifially are your target you might be better off picking a different language.  It's not really an ideal starter project.  However you can have a lot of fun just developing your Python skills and run it on platforms where it's better supported - like the one where you plan to run VS Code
!

Answer (score 1):

I explained majority of what I thought in comment, but I'll just duplicate and add some key concepts you need to study.

> Visual studio code is a software app that allows you to edit text. It
>   is not tide to any language.  Developing for IOS or Android depends on
>   language, but not on the editor that you're using. From your question
>   it seems like you don't understand primary concepts of app development
>   or programming, so you better study this first.

Things you should study:

1. What is an application/program?
2. What is Python application (since you showed your interest in language)?
3. How basic apps run?
4. What is IDE and why do you need it?

Your question got many "downvotes" because you don't quite know what you're asking.
Hope this will help!